# Save As Dialog Box C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have one export method which gives me one .txt file. That file is getting saved on *Downloads* on my machine.

I want one save as pop up which ask user where they want to save that downloaded file, as well as they can name the file.

Comment: using Microsoft.Win32 is the key, there is a savefiledialog ;)^EDIT: sry didnt read asp.net but this could help: http://forums.asp.net/t/1078969.aspx?SaveFileDialog+in+ASP+NET+

Comment: Does asp.net have a saveFileDialog perhaps? for windows forms has that available for that exact purpose.

Comment: If this is a web application, you can't have a simple "save as" dialog. You'll need to create one yourself.

Comment: The 'save as' dialog is implemented in the web-browser

Comment: People choose where to save their files in browser settings. It's a security issue.

Comment: Your site cannot override the browser behaviour.  Each browser has own preferences on where and whether to prompt for downloads

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the situation where the browser is automatically saving the file and not asking where to save it?

This is controlled by the [`Content-Disposition` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) (19.5.1). If you add a header like

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.txt"
```

then the browser understands that it is an attachment and should ask what to do with it.

However, the browser may choose to do something else with it.